# How to render bootstrap dropdown above the object?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this HTML which renders a bootstrap dropdown under the object. It is possible to make it apear above the Title button?

```
<div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Title
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a>Option 1</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a>Option 1</a></li>
                 (various number of <li>)
          </ul>
        </div>
```

I've tried with `position:absolute; top:50px` but doesn't work for any case.
Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just move the `<a>` tag under the `<ul>`?

Comment: Like this? http://jsbin.com/IniHIKi/1/

Comment: @letiagoalves yes, but should work with any number of <li>

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is by default part of what Bootstrap can do. It's in the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#buttonDropdowns) under **Button Dropdowns - Dropup menus**

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
```

As it's absolutely positioned, you will need to have some space above the button so you can see the drop up menu, so I wouldn't use it at the top of a page.

I've set up a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9wy8b/) for you. If you remove the `<br>` at the top, you'll see that the menu options are hidden at the top of the output box.

Comment: For bootstrap [version 3](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns)

Comment: Still exists in [version 3.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-dropdowns-dropup)

Answer (score 0):

you can rotate the container, and rotate the items inside to appear normal :)
its just a few lines of css.

css:

```
.dropdown {
 left: 40px;
 top: 150px; 
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.dropdown a, .dropdown button {
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.dropdown a {
  padding: 5px 35px 5px 5px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin-left: -18px !important;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qj0Led41/)

IMO its very simple and elegant solution, the only downside you will have to use transform or 'left' with `important` to override Bootstrap's direct styling on the element to adjust the opened menu